# Regular Expression performance issue to pasrse big contents

Tags: regex, performance

Suppose i have to filter some text from a file. Then i have 2 solutions

1. Either I take all the contents of file into
   a single variable(like fileinputstream or something else) which can be
   parsed using regular expression.
2. Or i use looping to read file line
   by line. Then i apply either regular
   expression or some string function on each line.

Which method will be better and faster?

Comment: Not clear enough for me.  Do you wish to filter text out, and is the text you want to filter on multi-line?

Comment: That would depends on what kind of string function you're talking about. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Suppose im in java, then either i can use whole file as CharSequence for parsing. Or i can parse each line using readline().

Answer (score 0):

Most regular expression libraries (such as PCRE) are very efficient and highly optimized, so I say go with the first option.

But of course if performance is very important to you, you should use a profiler anyway; it could give you a better answer for your exact situation.